# Customization Layered Navigation

Tags: layered-navigation

In my filter.phtml i have this code:

```
<select name="layered-nav-select" onChange="setLocation(this.value)">
<option selected="selected" value="#">Please Select </option>
<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>             
        <?php if ($_item->getCount() > 0): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>">
                <?php
                echo $_item->getLabel();
                if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()):
                    echo '(' . $_item->getCount() . ')';
                endif; 
                ?>
            </option>               
        <?php else: ?>
            <option value="#">
                <?php
                echo $_item->getLabel();
                if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()):
                    echo '(' . $_item->getCount() . ')';
                endif; 
                ?>
            </option>
        <?php endif; ?>     
<?php endforeach ?>
```

code is working correctly see link: http://prntscr.com/b2ibsg

But I need the Filter name instead of Please Select , for example in first filter instead Please select - display Manufacturer name,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get the filter frontend label, replace `Please select` with the following:

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getName()) ?>
```

See `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php` to see what the method does.